# GIF muxer supports only a single video GIF stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg

so I'm trying to watermark a folder full of gifs but I get an error saying that I can only work with one GIF stream at the time, is there a way to circumvent this?

```
@echo off
setlocal
for %%G in ("%~dp0gifs\*.gif") do (
    ffmpeg -i %%G -i Watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2[v0];[1:v][v0]scale2ref=trunc(iw/5):trunc(ih/16)[logo][0v];[0v][logo]overlay=W-w-3:H-h-4 [v]" -map "[v]" -codec:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 %%~nG.gif
    )
)
endlocal
pause
```

The error from `ffmpeg`:

```
[gif @ 0x7ff212801c00] GIF muxer supports only a single video GIF stream.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
```

Comment: You should always show the exact errors, and even better is to show the complete log or console output from `ffmpeg`. H.264 video doesn't work in GIF. I'm guessing you meant to use `%%~nG.mp4`.

Comment: Oh alright, the exact error says "GIF mixur supports only a single video GIF stream" and I didn't know that H.264 doesn't work with GIF, I just reused my code for watermarking videos and applied it to GIF.

Comment: What happens is that I have webm files I need to cut down into a sample gif and add a logo on them, I already turned them into gifs and I tried the solution on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46060013/how-to-add-watermark-in-a-gif-with-ffmpeg but it seems I'm on the wrong track because it crashes the console when I run my script.

Comment: No need to pre-encode anything to GIF *then* add the overlay–that's wasteful and unecessary. You can do all of that in the same command. Regarding the crash you should always test the ffmpeg command manually, unscripted in cmd before you attempt to script it so you can reduce the complexity and help simplify the process of elimination (and get faster answers here).

Comment: OHH, of course, you are right, I know how to watermark videos so I can watermark them before turning them into gifs, so that partially solves my issue, still, I'd be doing two encodings for the GIFs that I already have, 1st turn them into videos with the watermark, 2. turn them back into GIFs, if somebody happens to know how to overlay images into a GIF that'd be greatly appreciated, I can't seem to implement the only answer I found in another thread.

Comment: I provided an answer to the original issue encountered. As for your new problem I recommend a new question. If it is unrelated to the scripting just make it a plain `ffmpeg` question without the scripting and ask at Super User.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

H.264 can't be muxed into GIF. Either:

- Remove `-codec:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18` to output actual GIF, or
- Change the output `.gif` to `.mp4` to output H.264 video in MP4 container

Comment: I removed the H.264 part and it worked nicely, thank you.