# FFmpeg how to add drawtext on filter complex along with watermark and palettegen

Tags: ffmpeg, animated-gif, watermark, drawtext

thanks to many posts on stack overflow I could come till here: [How to add watermark in a gif with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46060013/how-to-add-watermark-in-a-gif-with-ffmpeg) which i can convert mp4 into animated gif with moderate quality and watermark on. But I'd like to add the drawtext too in these lines.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0]fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos[bg];[bg][1]overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5,palettegen" palette.png
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i watermark.png -i palette.png -filter_complex "[0]fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos[bg];[bg][1]overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5[x];[x][2]paletteuse=dither=bayer:bayer_scale=3" output.gif
```

Would it be possible through filter_complex by adding another [ ]? Thanks a lot to everyone

Answer (score 2):

You can add [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) after [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay).

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0]fps=10,scale=320:-1[bg];[bg][1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10:format=auto,drawtext=text='your text here':fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" output.gif
```

This will add text centered in video and overlay will be placed in the lower right.

Comment: wow, that was a fast reply. Thanks but... doesn't work on me..the drawtext part doesn't work. Do you think it is related to shell_exec in php?

Comment: $cmd1 = "$ffmpeg -ss 00:00:02 -t 00:00:02 -i $file_full_path -i $watermark -filter_complex '[0]fps=15,scale=200:113:flags=lanczos[bg];[bg][1]overlay=5:5,drawtext=text='foo',palettegen' $palette";

Comment: @Groovekingg I need more details than just "doesn't work". What is the actual command? What does the ffmpeg log show?

Comment: @llogan I think it was merely missing enough drawtext parameters to make it visible. This variation works for me:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -i palette.png -filter_complex "[0]fps=10,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos[bg];[bg][1]overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5,drawtext=fontfile=OpenSans-Regular.ttf:text='Foo':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:x=(w-tw)/2:y=(h/PHI)+th [x];[x][2]paletteuse=dither=bayer:bayer_scale=3" output.gif

Comment: @PlenusFranckly Probably a good guess. I only used the default which makes a black, small size text in the upper left. I was assuming users would modify to suit their needs. Maybe I'll change it.